# specifying the maximum value for an integer in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I want to enter an integer value into a column of phpmyadmin sql table and I want that value to be less than or equal to a particular value, say 100. If it is greater than 100, I don't want it inserted. How do I achieve doing it?

Comment: Check the value first before inserting it to the database

Comment: That was what I was thinking. But if it could be checked in phpmyadmin page, my job would be easier.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. And how can you say that it is much easier?

Comment: just check it in your code using if condition and if your condition satisfied only then you will insert record into database this would be easier and good way

Comment: Normally you should do this in the create table statement within the CHECK constraint but MySQL doesnt support this.. next option would be to define a trigger

Comment: @CarlJan Because my code is a mess

Comment: Then clean your codes first, the if/else condition that will be used is not complicated

Comment: @CarlJan Your comments aren't really helping